# LU decomposition using python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix-factorization

I need to implement a LU decomposition and then compare it to the `np.linalg.solve` function from numpy.

The function in the code (see below) runs without any problems, but when I use it to solve a matrix I keep getting an error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

on the line:

```
L[i][j] = (A2[i][j] - s2) / U[j][j]
```

Here is the whole code:

```
 def matrixMul(A, B):
        TB = zip(*B)
        return [[sum(ea*eb for ea,eb in zip(a,b)) for b in TB] for a in A]

    def pivotize(m):
        #Creates the pivoting matrix for m.
        n = len(m)
        ID = [[float(i == j) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
        for j in range(n):
            row = max(range(j, n), key=lambda i: abs(m[i][j]))
            if j != row:
                ID[j], ID[row] = ID[row], ID[j]
        return ID

    def lu(A):
        #Decomposes a nxn matrix A by PA=LU and returns L, U and P.
        n = len(A)
        L = [[0.0] * n for i in range(n)]
        U = [[0.0] * n for i in range(n)]
        P = pivotize(A)
        A2 = matrixMul(P, A)
        for j in range(n):
            L[j][j] = 1.0
            for i in range(j+1):
                s1 = sum(U[k][j] * L[i][k] for k in range(i))
                U[i][j] = A2[i][j] - s1
            for i in range(j, n):
                s2 = sum(U[k][j] * L[i][k] for k in range(j))
                L[i][j] = (A2[i][j] - s2) / U[j][j]
        return (L)

    A = np.array([[1,1,3],[5,3,1],[2,3,1]])
    b = np.array([2,3,-1])
    print('LU factorization: ', lu(A))

    A = np.array([[1,1,3],[5,3,1],[2,3,1]])
    b = np.array([2,3,-1])
    print('Internal solver : ', np.linalg.solve(A,b))
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `matrixMul` method is not correct. Try this:

```
matrixMul([[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]])
```

This is multiplying two identity matrices, and should return `[[1, 0], [0, 1]]`. When I run it, it returns `[[1, 0], []]`. This means that `A2`, inside your `lu` has only a single row, the rest are empty. Thus the index error when `i == 1` and `j == 0`.

This reason for the failure is that `TB` is a `zip` object. Those can only be iterated over a single time, consuming the iterator. I don't actually think you need the `TB` object at all, just iterate over elements of `B`.

```
def matrixMul(A, B):
    return [[sum(ea*eb for ea,eb in zip(a,b)) for b in B] for a in A]
```

This returns the desired output:

```
>>> matrixMul([[1, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [0, 1]])
>>> [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```

EDIT:

By the way, there are still other problems with your solution. Yours and NumPy's versions still don't match. But the solution here will fix your index error.

Comment: Any idea how I can match the NumPy solution?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but your inner loop in the `lu` method looks suspicious to me. I'm not familiar with the algorithm you're implementing. I've only worked with the Doolittle algorithm, which subtracts off successive rows of the original matrix A, not the U/L product you've got going on in your innermost loops (which is where my suspicions arise). Check out the Wikipedia page for info on the Doolittle algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Doolittle_algorithm.